# Is the address of the first element of a vector fixed?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, vector

For example if I do something like this:

```
vector<int> myvector;
myvector.push_back(100);
int * ptr = &(myvector[0]);
myvector.clear();
myvector.push_back(10);
```

Will ptr still be valid?  Or could it now be pointing to garbage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

23.2.3 §4 says:

> `a.clear()` [...] **invalidates all references, pointers, and iterators** referring to the elements of `a` and may invalidate the past-the-end iterator.

Since there is no such thing as "un-invalidation", using `ptr` after `clear` results in undefined behavior.

On a side note, the parenthesis in `&(myvector[0])` are not needed. Postfix operators always have higher precedence than prefix operators in C++, so writing `&myvector[0]` is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

It could be pointing to garbage. `vector` reallocates memory as needed when an instance grows or shrinks so you can't rely on the address not changing. That's why the types used for `vector` have to obey STL-compatible constraints like copy-ability. That's also why `auto_ptr` isn't safe in STL containers.